# Why does the Bonbon song question have so many downvotes?

Tags: discussion

I know it's been marked as a duplicate (although it's not exactly the same as "We're no strangers to code golf"), but what warrants 13 downvotes on the question? There have been worse questions asked on this site with far less.

The question in question can be found [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/38295/the-bonbon-song).

Comment: My fabulous question has been deleted!

Comment: For some context can you give an example an open question you would deem worse?

Comment: Questions like [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/38259/why-is-sha-256-considered-collision-free), which aren't even code golf. I know the question was bad, but it's the most downvotes I have ever seen and was wondering if there was something I was missing.

Comment: @TheWobbuffet That's probably to stop you from losing anymore rep.

Comment: @BetaDecay Then that's good, and I don't have to make a digitally modified recording of the song now!

Comment: @TheWobbuffet You waere *actually* going to do that?!

Comment: @BetaDecay Yes, why? :P I mean, it's a real song I made up that my friends and I sing frequently

Comment: @TheWobbuffet Were/Are you meaning to release it? Or was it just for the purposes of this challenge?

Comment: @BetaDecay It was just something to put on the challenge to add non-boringness

Comment: "Page not found".

Comment: @Poldie The question has since been deleted.

Answer (score 17):

Because it's **boooorring**, that's why.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep in mind not to post **boooorring** challenges.

Answer (score 13):

The question has no interesting twists or requirements. All it is is a variant of Ninety Nine Bottles of Beer on the Wall which has been golfed to death.

If the numbers were in some kind of special pattern or something it might have gained upvotes but as it stands, it's an age-old programming puzzle requiring only a for loop.

Basically, the challenge is too easy and has been done many times before.